# How can I track/login to stolen MacBook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, find-my-mac

My MBP got stolen in January 2017 and is not shown in *Find My iPhone* **but** I just found out that it shows up under signed-in devices in iTunes with the serial number and the first name of the new user (Aleksej).

Is there any way to track the MBPs location with the serial number or the sign-in information?

Comment: What country is this in? It will be helpful to know as this might involve the law.

Answer (score 1):

**No**

Unfortunately, There is no way to track it to an accurate location without Find My iPhone enabled. If your able to get the devices serial number your best bet would be to file a police report at your local police station.

If it was stolen back in January odds are it has already been erased and/or resold. So even if there would’ve been a way to track it, you wouldn’t be able to anymore.

**Edit 1**

If you enable 2 step verification, if the thief tries to log into you Apple ID on the stolen computer, it will show on your other devices an authentication code for that devices, aswell as the location of the device that is requesting permission.

So if the thief tries to log into your Apple ID and you have Two Step Verification enable, it will show you the stolen devices location.

Apple cannot track your device as it would most likely violate some privacy policy, though if you give them your consent they might be able to track your device. I would suggest you contact them and see what they can do.

Comment: Hi Matthew, thank you for your answer. I can see that Aleksej (the thief or buyer of my stolen laptop) is now using the MBP and he's logged in with my Apple ID (however that is possible as I've changed my PW several times since then). I really think there must be a way for apple to track that. My hopes are of course low but seeing that MBP logged in gave me some faint hope.

Comment: @MichaelSchmitz I updated my answer with a few other ways you might be able to track it.

Comment: Don't deal with Apple yourself. Contact the _police_ and have them subpoena the information from Apple, they should know how to do it. By law, Apple has to provide them, for example, the IP address your laptop signed into. Otherwise, Apple will hide behind the privacy policy.

Comment: @user71659 My understanding is you can't get an subpoena issued without having a court case. For example if your trying to get the person charged, but you need evidence that its them, then you can get a subpoena issued. I will look into this though.

Comment: @MatthewN Nope. All you need is an official criminal investigation. 18 USC 2703 (d)

Comment: @MatthewN Thank you Matthew. I'll contact Apple these days and keep you posted. I've contacted the police already back then. But I can ask them again as well if there's a way to get the req. information. But as that is rather an international case (stolen in Germany, Apple wherever, Aleksej most likely in Russia or neighborhood) and the value rather "low" (4k EUR) my hopes are rather low as well. But asking doesn't cost anything we say. Give me a couple of weeks. I'll try just out of curiosity.